# one code base for iphone generic application?

Tags: iphone, generics, codebase

I have built a generic application which can handle different content data - but for each content data, it will be a different iphone application (with a different name).

I would like of couse to only keep one code base for all these different apps (as it would be easier maintenance) but I have 2 questions:

1- I would need to change the appname in the buildsettings, etc.. and may be it is going to be an overkill...? especially with the upload process then...? What are your experiences in that domain and what would you recommend me to do?

2- how can I have all the pictures for logo (Icon.png, etc...) to co-exist into one app? For the moment, I have a global variable (as a singleton pattern) that I switch to change appname and loaded data inside the program

Thanks in advance for your help

Cheers,
geebee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily, it's what most developers do in their lite versions. All you have to do is add another target to create a new app out of the same code and use that global variable.

In order to change the images included in the app you simply edit the target and under the copy bundle resources menu remove the unnecessary resources. You'll notice that when you add a new resource you have the option to include it in any one or more of your targets. Simply select the one that you want and it will only be accessible to that target.

The reason that this works is that each target can have its very own info.plist. All the settings and resources can be separate, and the code can be different using your #ifdef global_var.

Here's a slightly outdated tutorial that should get you started if you need it.
http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2098

Comment: this is great help - thanks - and cool link - I am on my way to do it

Answer (score 0):

For each application name add one target.

Create one xyz-info.plist for each of the target. (in this case for the xyz.app)

In each of the xyz-info.plist assign the appropriate icon files etc.

Within your build phases for each of the targets you will define which images go with which app.